# Having trouble with this shell script task

Tags: shell

Assignment
Write a program to go on the Internet and get the price of a stock.
Usage like:
getprice (stock symbol)
For example:

```
getprice goog
getprice msft
```

For 40%

```
We will get stock quotes from Yahoo, from pages like these:
    http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog
    http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=msft 

We use Yahoo because stock price is nicely delimited by tags. Something like:
    <span id="yfs_l84_goog">529.24</span>
    <span id="yfs_l84_msft">41.60</span> 

The first line of your script constructs the URL needed, given the command-line argument.
Use wget to download the URL to a file.
Test that is working, and the stock price is found somewhere in the file.

When the above is working: Use grep to search the file for the relevant line.
Test that you can extract the single line with the stock price on it.
```

For 100%

```
When the above is working: Use sed to remove from start-of-line to <span>
See string matching / regular expressions.
See start of line, end of line.
".*" matches any sequence of characters.
Check that this works before proceeding.

When the above is working: Use sed to remove from </span> to end of line.
Your program should now just print the price.
```

Here is what I have:

```
wget -q -O - http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=$1 |
grep -o '<span id="yfs_l84_goog">.*</span>*' | 
cut -c1-37 |
sed 's|<span id="yfs_l84_goog".||g' | 
sed 's|</span>||g'
```

when I enter getprice goog it works but when I enter getprice msft it doesn't can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your commands all hard code `goog`

Comment: There is a literal `goog` in line two and four of your script, you might want to parametrize that.

Comment: Yes I only noticed that now. How do I grep it without goog or msft?

Answer (score 0):

100%:

```
wget -q -O - http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=$1 |
grep -o "<span id=\"yfs_l84_$1\">.*</span>*" | 
cut -c1-37 |
sed "s|<span id=\"yfs_l84_$1\".||g" | 
sed 's|</span>||g'| 
sed 's|</||g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getprice () {
wget -q -O - http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=$1 | sed -n "s/^.*yfs_l84_"$1"\">\([^<]*\)[<].*$/\1/p"
}
```

To get price goog value :

```
getprice goog
#726.82
```

To get price msft value :

```
getprice msft
#53.07
```